# SQLiteException: Unrecognized token when reading from database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've created an SQLite database inside application, populated it and now I'm trying to read from it. The app keeps crashing and this is the logcat I receive:

```
12-30 05:53:18.008: E/AndroidRuntime(6205): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testparsing/com.example.testparsing.Urnik}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "4c" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT predmet FROM predmeti WHERE dan=PONEDELJEK and ura=2 and oddelek=4c
```

Function for reading from database:

```
Cursor getSubject(String dan, int ura, String oddelek){
    String[] columnNames = new String[1];
    columnNames[0] = SQLiteHelper.PREDMET;
    String selection = SQLiteHelper.DAN+"="+dan+" and "+SQLiteHelper.URA+"="+ura+" and "+SQLiteHelper.ODDELEK+"="+oddelek;
    open();
    return db.query(
            SQLiteHelper.IME_TABELE, 
            columnNames, 
            selection, 
            null, null, null, null);
}
```

How I'm trying to read:

```
TextView tw1p = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tview1p);
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

Cursor c = db.getSubject("PONEDELJEK", 2, "4c");
String predmet = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.PREDMET));
tw1p.setText(predmet);
```

A screenshot of table, just to prove that oddelek "4c" in fact does exist:
[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
SELECT predmet FROM predmeti WHERE dan=PONEDELJEK and ura=2 and oddelek=4c
```

You need to quote your string literals, for example:

```
SELECT predmet FROM predmeti WHERE dan='PONEDELJEK' and ura=2 and oddelek='4c'
```

But it's better to use `?` placeholder for literals:

```
SELECT predmet FROM predmeti WHERE dan=? and ura=? and oddelek=?
```

and change your `null` `selectionArgs` to

```
new String[] { dan, Integer.toString(ura), oddelek }
```

Comment: this did the trick. thx!  Don't forget to escape single quotes as is: \'

Answer (score 2):

issue is due to missing quotes only :-

Example

```
 db.delete(TABLE_NA,E, ADDRESS + "= '" + address + "'", null);
```

Please check below field
+ "= '" + address + "'"

> {Issue as address is string so it should be under 'address'  }

Answer (score 1):

```
String selection = SQLiteHelper.DAN+"="+dan+" and "+SQLiteHelper.URA+"="+ura+" and "+SQLiteHelper.ODDELEK+"='"+oddelek+"'";
```

Replace with this and check

Comment: Thanks, i was missing single quote after equals "='"+xxx+"'";