# Barcode Scanner Android Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Good day sir/ma'am, everytime I press save the item name, item price and item description, my app automatically crash and directed to main screen. this is the error. would you mind to help me?

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: app.num.barcodescannerproject, PID: 15141
>                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "8850007011743jumel50wew" (code 1): , while
>   compiling: INSERT INTO scanresults VALUES(8850007011743jumel50wew);
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:906)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:517)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1704)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1635)
>                         at app.num.barcodescannerproject.popupDialouge$1.onClick(popupDialouge.java:36)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4909)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20390)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5877)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15141 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

This is my code

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("barcodescan",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scanresults(barcode VARCHAR,item VARCHAR,price VARCHAR ,note VARCHAR);");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO scanresults VALUES("+Barcode+item.getText().toString()+itemPrice.getText().toString()+itemNote.getText().toString()+");");
            Toast.makeText(popupDialouge.this, "Item Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are using wrong methods for the insert methods.Add a method inside the button click, and follow below example.

```
public void InsertScanResult(String barcodeItem,String itemPrice,String itemNote)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("BarCodeColumnNamed", barcodeItem);
    cv.put("PriceColumnName",itemPrice);
    cv.put("ItemColumnName", itemNote);
    db.insert("YourTableNamed", null, cv);
}
```

You can get example from [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: @Jumel Hermoso This would be highly useful for you to get started with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the quotes:

`db.execSQL("INSERT INTO scanresults VALUES('"Barcode+ "', '" +item.getText().toString()+"', '" + itemPrice.getText().toString()+"', '" +itemNote.getText().toString()+"');");`

However, you should really consider using prepared statements...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to quote your Strings inside your SQL-statement

see : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838233/sqliteexception-unrecognized-token-when-reading-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing raw statement using `db.execSQL()`, its better to use most preferred built-in method `db.insert()` to `insert` data through `ContentValues`.

**Update your `onClick()` method as below:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("barcodescan",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scanresults(barcode VARCHAR, item VARCHAR, price VARCHAR , note VARCHAR);");

    // Data to be inserted
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("barcode", Barcode);
    values.put("item", item.getText().toString());
    values.put("price", itemPrice.getText().toString());
    values.put("note", itemNote.getText().toString());

    // Insert data
    db.insert("scanresults", null, values);

    Toast.makeText(popupDialouge.this, "Item Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

Hope this will help~